# maven dependency tree showing dependency that is not present in parent jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3

I ran maven dependency:tree on my module. Here is the snippet of this output.

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api:jar:3.6.0:compile
```

I see `transitive dependency` to `commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6` from `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.2`.

but I could not find this jar inside `$M2_HOME/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.2/httpclient-4.3.2.jar`.

I also did NOT see this jar located in 'referenced Libraries' or 'maven dependencies' in Eclipse. My project `Base64Util` class from `commons-codec` and it compiles fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency is defined in the POM as you can see here :

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.2/httpclient-4.3.2.pom

There is a compile dependency to commons-codec. It has a parent pom reference to httpcomponents-client, which defines the version as 1.6 as can be seen here:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.3.2/httpcomponents-client-4.3.2.pom

So the maven output is correct and the library will be provided. Now if you use a class from this library in your code, I would recommend to have an explicit dependency in your pom.

Maven builds this tree of dependencies to see which libraries are needed, as each jar is only containing its own classes and not the dependencies. Maven will verify that if multiple libraries ask the same dependency that a version is used which will work with both libraries. Sometimes it can't find a solution and will throw its hands in the air with a dependency resolution error. When it has the list of libraries it will download them and put them on the java classpath for compilation, etc...

This is needed as the normal java classloader puts all classes in the same namespace. This is not always the case, e.g. servlet containers make a classloader per war, osgi containers one per bundle, however all these systems come at a price : weird ClassCast exceptions because a class is loaded in multiple classloaders. That is the reason that jars do not contain their dependencies in a selfcontained [uberjar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

Comment: I am not questioning the maven outputl. But  I am wondering why the jar for `httpclient` does not contain the `commons-codec` since it is dependent?

Comment: That is not how maven (or java) works. All libraries are stored separately in the maven repository, downloaded and put on the java classpath before execution.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain why jars do not contain their dependencies.

Comment: excellent!. I see my project had downloaded multiple versions of `codec` jars possibly each maven dependency that I am using different versions of `codec`..not sure if this is a good practice? but this is something, I cannot control since dependency might depend on particular `codec` version..

Comment: In practice it is no problem. Let maven deal with selecting the best version.  Unless you use jars from very different ages, the dependencies should be close enough that maven can find a match. Very exceptionally you have to tell maven to 'exclude' a transient dependency from one of your dependencies to break a deadlock.